# Django middleware is looped when using process_view

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

Django middleware is looped when using process_view

I am trying to use the method to redirect a process during middleware.

Middleware

```
from django.urls        import reverse
from django.shortcuts   import redirect, render

class CustomMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
    
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
       
        return redirect(reverse('check_license'))
```

Urls

```
path('check-license', views.check_license, name='check_license')
```

View

```
def check_license():
    return render(request, 'check_license.html')
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do that you have put just a redirect in the middleware? And you also don't consider for which view you redirect of course it goes into infinite recursion (kind of - actually an infinite redirect loop).

Comment: You should only process it once. Since process_view is called before the view

Comment: I am looking to redirect to this page if the license is not valid. For example.

Comment: you need to introduce some sort of if-else condition to break the recursion, ie redirect to that view only if some condition is met and view is not check_license.

Comment: if true:
            return redirect(reverse('check_license'))
        else:
            pass

Comment: Regardless of the condition and when to enter the if. The loop is processed

Comment: Something like: `if not license_valid() and request.path_info != "/check-license":` (Assuming `/check-license` to be the url of the redirecting view).

Comment: Very good. Simple thinking. I think it's hours in front of the laptop. And I didn't think about this idea. Thank you very much.